# Turn array elements into new rows of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm currently working on restructuring some data, so that it is in a more usable format. My DataFrame describes properties of 2 types of items (let us call them A and B). Currently I've used `.explode()` on my columns for A (group here referring to which where together before), since it is the focus. It effectively has a structure like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 9, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]],
        [0, 1, 2, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]],
        [1, 3, 3, [1, 2], [-5, 1]],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'],
)
print(df)
```

```py
   Group  A_x  A_y        B_m          B_n
0      0    4    9  [8, 7, 3]  [-10, 5, 2]
1      0    1    2  [8, 7, 3]  [-10, 5, 2]
2      1    3    3     [1, 2]      [-5, 1]
```

Problem I'm having is that I want to turn the 'B_m' and 'B_n' columns into 2 columns each with only 1 element per row (akin to using `.explode()`), iterating to get all pairs of 2 (no dupes). It should look as follows:

```py
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 9, 8, -10, 7, 5],
        [0, 4, 9, 8, -10, 3, 2],
        [0, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2],
        [0, 1, 2, 8, -10, 7, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 8, -10, 3, 2],
        [0, 1, 2, 7, 5, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 3, 1, -5, 2, 1],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m1', 'B_n1', 'B_m2', 'B_n2'],
)
print(expected)
```

```py
   Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_n1  B_m2  B_n2
0      0    4    9     8   -10     7     5
1      0    4    9     8   -10     3     2
2      0    4    9     7     5     3     2
3      0    1    2     8   -10     7     5
4      0    1    2     8   -10     3     2
5      0    1    2     7     5     3     2
6      1    3    3     1    -5     2     1
```

Here 'B_m' [[8, 7, 3]] becomes 'B_m1' [[8], [8], [7]] and 'B_m2' [[7], [3], [3]] for each of the three combinations (8,7), (8,3) and (7,3).

Been trying to us a for loop over all of the combinations using itertools. Then I take np.isin for each of the 2 values, creating masks that are then used to grab only the part of any column that corresponds to the indices I want. I convert using `.item()` from a 1 element array to an int (or float in my actual case). That means I can now take the columns for A and add with the new series I've taken using my masks.

```py
from itertools import combinations

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m1', 'B_n1', 'B_m2', 'B_n2'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():    
    for values in list(combinations(row.B_m, 2)):
        mask0 = np.isin(row.B_m, values[0])
        mask1 = np.isin(row.B_m, values[1])
        temp0 = sample[['B_m', 'B_n']].apply(lambda x: x[mask0])
        temp0 = temp0.apply(lambda x: x.item())
        temp1 = sample[['B_m', 'B_n']].apply(lambda x: x[mask1])
        temp1 = temp1.apply(lambda x: x.item())
    
        df = pd.concat(
            objs=[df, pd.concat([row['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y'], temp0, temp1])],
            axis=0,
        )
```

Hope you have suggestions for how to make this work, not necessarily in the manner above. In fact, I'd prefer to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: I've produced the expected result, but the result you're asking for is a bit strange. Right now, you're pairing up the pairs from groups B_m and B_n according to how the elements are positioned within the list. I suspect that what you really need is to get all pairs of pairs, regardless of how items are ordered in each list.

Comment: Sorry that I've been insufficiently clear. It is very much on purpose that the elements of a row with group of value 0 isn't "mixed" with those of 1. They represent different groups, and as such the first solution you proposed Ben does accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Leaning on [@Ben Grossmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann)'s interpretation, minus the `numpy` dependency:

```py
from itertools import combinations

import pandas as pd


def make_pairs(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    pairs = (
        df[col]
        # Create 2-pair combinations of each list in the series 
        .apply(lambda x: [*combinations(iterable=x, r=2)])
        # Explode into a series of 2-item lists
        .explode()
    )
    # Construct a dataframe of the using the original index for joining
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=pairs.to_list(),
        index=pairs.index,
        columns=[f"{col}{i}" for i in range(1, 3)]
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [0, 4, 9, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]],
        [0, 1, 2, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]],
        [1, 3, 3, [1, 2], [-5, 1]],
    ],
    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'],
)
# Join everything together.
out = (
    df.join(
        other=[
            make_pairs(df=df, col="B_m"),
            make_pairs(df=df, col="B_n"),
        ],
    )
    # Drop the unneeded columns.
    .drop(columns=["B_m", "B_n"])
)
print(out)
```

```py
   Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_m2  B_n1  B_n2
0      0    4    9     8     7   -10     5
0      0    4    9     8     7   -10     2
0      0    4    9     8     7     5     2
0      0    4    9     8     3   -10     5
0      0    4    9     8     3   -10     2
0      0    4    9     8     3     5     2
0      0    4    9     7     3   -10     5
0      0    4    9     7     3   -10     2
0      0    4    9     7     3     5     2
1      0    1    2     8     7   -10     5
1      0    1    2     8     7   -10     2
1      0    1    2     8     7     5     2
1      0    1    2     8     3   -10     5
1      0    1    2     8     3   -10     2
1      0    1    2     8     3     5     2
1      0    1    2     7     3   -10     5
1      0    1    2     7     3   -10     2
1      0    1    2     7     3     5     2
2      1    3    3     1     2    -5     1
```

Comment: I was wondering how I'd do this without numpy. The .to_list() method and join are clever

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that works. I found it helpful to avoid looping over rows and take advantage of the explode method.

```
from itertools import combinations 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# for use in apply call
def to_pairs(x):
    return [[a,b] for a,b in combinations(x,2)]

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 4, 9, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]], [0, 1, 2, [8, 7, 3],
                    [-10, 5, 2]], [1, 3, 3, [1, 2], [-5, 1]]],
                    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'])
cols = ['B_m','B_n'] # specify columns with the lists

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(to_pairs)

df = df.explode(cols).reset_index(drop = True)
data = np.hstack([np.vstack(df[col]) for col in cols])
column_names = [col + str(i) for col in cols for i in range(1,3)]
df_right = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = column_names)

df_result = pd.concat([df.drop(columns = cols), df_right], axis = 1)
df_result
```

The result:

```
   Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_m2  B_n1  B_n2
0      0    4    9     8     7   -10     5
1      0    4    9     8     3   -10     2
2      0    4    9     7     3     5     2
3      0    1    2     8     7   -10     5
4      0    1    2     8     3   -10     2
5      0    1    2     7     3     5     2
6      1    3    3     1     2    -5     1
```

---

Here's code that produces what I suspect you really want, including all pairs of pairs.

```
from itertools import combinations 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def to_pairs(x):
    return [[a,b] for a,b in combinations(x,2)]


df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 4, 9, [8, 7, 3], [-10, 5, 2]], [0, 1, 2, [8, 7, 3],
                    [-10, 5, 2]], [1, 3, 3, [1, 2], [-5, 1]]],
                    columns=['Group', 'A_x', 'A_y', 'B_m', 'B_n'])
cols = ['B_m','B_n']

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(to_pairs)
    df = df.explode(col)

df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
data = np.hstack([np.vstack(df[col]) for col in cols])
column_names = [col + str(i) for col in cols for i in range(1,3)]
df_right = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = column_names)

df_result = pd.concat([df.drop(columns = cols), df_right], axis = 1)
df_result
```

The result:

```
    Group  A_x  A_y  B_m1  B_m2  B_n1  B_n2
0       0    4    9     8     7   -10     5
1       0    4    9     8     7   -10     2
2       0    4    9     8     7     5     2
3       0    4    9     8     3   -10     5
4       0    4    9     8     3   -10     2
5       0    4    9     8     3     5     2
6       0    4    9     7     3   -10     5
7       0    4    9     7     3   -10     2
8       0    4    9     7     3     5     2
9       0    1    2     8     7   -10     5
10      0    1    2     8     7   -10     2
11      0    1    2     8     7     5     2
12      0    1    2     8     3   -10     5
13      0    1    2     8     3   -10     2
14      0    1    2     8     3     5     2
15      0    1    2     7     3   -10     5
16      0    1    2     7     3   -10     2
17      0    1    2     7     3     5     2
18      1    3    3     1     2    -5     1
```